# Al utilizar las sesiones de django-cassandra-engine obtengo un error en INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, cassandra

Estoy utilizando django-cassandra-engine para el almacenamiento de sesiones, cuando inicio el servidor me sale este error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sessions.models.Session doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

Los pasos que seguí son estos [link](http://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/guide/sessions/)

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_cassandra_engine.sessions']

SESSION_BACKEND = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'
```

Mi archivo settings:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
WORK_DIR = os.getcwd()


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_cassandra_engine',
    'django_cassandra_engine.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ....
]

SESSION_BACKEND = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = '.....urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(WORK_DIR, "templates"),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '.....wsgi.application'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-EC'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Guayaquil'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(WORK_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Hola Edgar, ¿podrías mostrar tu settings.py completo, por lo menos las partes relacionadas al `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Hola @César,  ya actualice la pregunta con mis settings

Comment: Al parecer por el mensaje se puede deducir que está utilizando la clase comentada en `INSTALLED_APPS` ,  es decir `django.contrib.sessions`

Comment: si quito lo comentado sigue pasando lo mismo  @Dev.Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el error es el nombre del setting de Django para  especificar el backend que se va a usar.

En vez de usar `SESSION_BACKEND` intenta cambiar a [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-engine):

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'
```

La documentación de django-cassandra-engine debe de estar desactualizada. Es por eso que te sale ese error ya que, por defecto, el valor de `SESSION_ENGINE` es:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

Pero como lo habías comentado, no lo encontraba. Con este cambio debería funcionar.

Comment: excelente, ese era el problema.  solo debía usar SESSION_ENGINE